# SQL query result should give max count

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT count(*) rcount
    , DATE(create_date) crdate
    , fk_account_id accid
    , fk_caa_payment_pool_id poolId 
FROM  caa_payment_confirmation_hdr 
WHERE fk_caa_payment_pool_id IN 
(
    SELECT pk_caa_payment_pool_id 
    FROM caa_payment_pool 
    WHERE is_deleted = 0
) 
AND create_date >= '2017-08-01'
GROUP BY crdate
    , poolId
```

I want result to display only max value, please help me out

Comment: Which max value? And is this sql server or mysql? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Looking to the invalid use off GROUP BY this is probably mysql

Comment: @Abdullah is this Mysql or Sql server?

Comment: SQL only, please help me out

Comment: You mean MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

ORDER the table based on count and then use [LIMIT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT count(*) rcount
    , DATE(create_date) crdate
    , fk_account_id accid
    , fk_caa_payment_pool_id poolId 
FROM  caa_payment_confirmation_hdr 
WHERE fk_caa_payment_pool_id IN 
(
    SELECT pk_caa_payment_pool_id 
    FROM caa_payment_pool 
    WHERE is_deleted = 0
) 
AND create_date >= '2017-08-01'
GROUP BY crdate
    , poolId
) A ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Why do you need the subquery to do this?  what is `cnt`? Just `order by rcount desc limit 1` right?